# Trying to clear form after submitting user input in vue 3

Tags: email, vuejs3, form-submit

I am trying to clear the form after a successful submission of the inputs from the user. What I tried seems to clear it after submission but it also triggers the rules of the input. I am using Vue 3 as the frontend part with emailjs latest version to send an email to a gmail account. I tried looking through other posts but what I got didn't help as I tried each of them.

```html
<template>
  <q-form
    method="post"
    style="max-width: 280px"
    align="center"
    @submit="Submit"
    @reset="onReset"
  >
    <q-input
      id="email"
      v-model="email"
      label="Email"
      lazy-rules
      :rules="[(val) => (val && val.length > 0) || 'Please type something']"
    >
      <template #prepend>
        <q-icon name="email" />
      </template>
    </q-input>

    <q-input
      id="name"
      v-model="name"
      label="Name"
      lazy-rules
      :rules="[(val) => (val && val.length > 0) || 'Please type something']"
    >
      <template #prepend>
        <q-icon name="person" />
      </template>
    </q-input>

    <q-input
      id="phone"
      v-model="phone"
      label="Phone number"
      lazy-rules
      :rules="[(val) => (val && val.length > 0) || 'Please type something']"
    >
      <template #prepend>
        <q-icon name="call" />
      </template>
    </q-input>

    <q-input
      id="table"
      v-model="table"
      label="Table number"
      lazy-rules
      :rules="[(val) => (val && val.length > 0) || 'Please type something']"
    >
      <template #prepend>
        <q-icon name="table" />
      </template>
    </q-input>

    <q-input
      id="food"
      v-model="food"
      label="Food"
      lazy-rules
      :rules="[(val) => (val && val.length > 0) || 'Please type something']"
    >
      <template #prepend>
        <q-icon name="money" />
      </template>
    </q-input>

    <q-btn flat color="blue" type="submit" label="Send"></q-btn>
    <q-btn flat color="red" type="reset" label="Reset"></q-btn>
  </q-form>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
import { ref } from 'vue';
import emailjs from '@emailjs/browser';

export default {
  setup() {
    const name = ref('');
    const food = ref('');
    const table = ref('');
    const phone = ref('');
    const email = ref('');

    const onReset = async () => {
      name.value = null;
      food.value = null;
      email.value = null;
      phone.value = null;
      table.value = null;
    };

    const Submit = () => {
      const param = {
        table: table.value,
        phone: phone.value,
        food: food.value,
        name: name.value,
        email: email.value
      };
      emailjs.send('service_id', 'template_id', param, 'public key').then(
        result => {
          console.log('SUCCESS!', result.status, result.text);
        },
        error => {
          console.log('FAILED...', error);
        }
      );

      name.value = null;
      food.value = null;
      email.value = null;
      phone.value = null;
      table.value = null;
    };
    return {
      Submit,
      onReset,
      email,
      table,
      phone,
      food,
      name
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read the [basic usage](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/form#usage) for Quasar's form which documents how to reset validation. As it explains, you need to assign a ref to `<q-form>` then call the `resetValidation()` method on that ref after you've submitted the form and cleared the inputs.  A basic example for your app is shown below:

```html
<q-form ref="myForm">
```

```js
setup () {
  const myForm = ref(null)

  function Submit () {
    emailjs.send().then(success => {
      if (success) {
        // after clearing inputs
        myForm.value.resetValidation()
      }
    })
  }

  return {
    myForm,
    Submit,
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks bruh but i tried it's not working

Comment: you'll need to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for additional help.  the above code is the appropriate way to solve your problem unless other errors or problems exist that we aren't aware of.  see my working example of your code with the above solution implemented in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v8t5dqow/)